# cudaMemGetInfo uses vram and returns the wrong value

Tags: c++, cuda

I am using cudaMemGetInfo in order to get the vram currently used by the system.

```
extern __host__ cudaError_t CUDARTAPI cudaMemGetInfo(size_t *free, size_t *total);
```

And I am having two problems :

- the main is that the free value returned is only right when the graphic device has almost no memory free for allocation. Otherwise it remains at about 20% memory used even when GPU-Z clearly states that about 80 % is used. And when I reach 95% memory used cudaMemGetInfo suddenly returns a good value. Note that the total memory is always correct.
- the second problem is that as soon as I use the function, video memory is allocated. At least 40mbytes but it can reach 400 on some graphic devices.

My code :

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

size_t Profiler::GetGraphicDeviceVRamUsage(int _NumGPU)
{
    cudaSetDevice(_NumGPU);

    size_t l_free = 0;
    size_t l_Total = 0;
    cudaError_t error_id = cudaMemGetInfo(&l_free, &l_Total);

    return (l_Total - l_free);
}
```

I tried with 5 different nvidia graphic devices. The problems are always the same.

Any idea ?

Comment: is the `cudaSetDevice(0)` a mistake? Do you only have 1 GPU in every system?

Comment: I only have one GPU on my current system. But you are right, I oversimplified my code example. Just updated the question.

Comment: Is the GPU also responsible for the graphics display ?

Comment: In my latest tests yes. But it doesn't make a difference when it is not. I already used my program on a machine with 4 GPUs. I faced the exact same previous two issues for all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your first point, I cannot reproduce this. If I expand your code into a complete example:

```
#include <iostream>
size_t GetGraphicDeviceVRamUsage(int _NumGPU)
{
    cudaSetDevice(_NumGPU);

    size_t l_free = 0;
    size_t l_Total = 0;
    cudaError_t error_id = cudaMemGetInfo(&l_free, &l_Total);

    return (l_Total - l_free);
}

int main()
{

    const size_t sz = 1 << 20;

    for(int i=0; i<20; i++) {
        size_t before = GetGraphicDeviceVRamUsage(0);
        char *p;
        cudaMalloc((void **)&p, sz);
        size_t after = GetGraphicDeviceVRamUsage(0);
        std::cout << i << " " << before << "->" << after << std::endl;
   }

   return cudaDeviceReset();
}
```

I get this on a linux machine:

```
$ ./meminfo 
0 82055168->83103744
1 83103744->84152320
2 84152320->85200896
3 85200896->86249472
4 86249472->87298048
5 87298048->88346624
6 88346624->89395200
7 89395200->90443776
8 90443776->91492352
9 91492352->92540928
10 92540928->93589504
11 93589504->94638080
12 94638080->95686656
13 95686656->96735232
14 96735232->97783808
15 97783808->98832384
16 98832384->99880960
17 99880960->100929536
18 100929536->101978112
19 101978112->103026688
```

and I get this on a Windows WDDM machine:

```
>meminfo
0 64126976->65175552
1 65175552->66224128
2 66224128->67272704
3 67272704->68321280
4 68321280->69369856
5 69369856->70418432
6 70418432->71467008
7 71467008->72515584
8 72515584->73564160
9 73564160->74612736
10 74612736->75661312
11 75661312->76709888
12 76709888->77758464
13 77758464->78807040
14 78807040->79855616
15 79855616->80904192
16 80904192->81952768
17 81952768->83001344
18 83001344->84049920
19 84049920->85098496
```

Both seem consistent to me.

On your second point: `cudaSetDevice` establishes a CUDA context on the device number which you pass to it, if no context already exists. Establishing a CUDA context will reserve memory for the runtime components required to run CUDA code. So it is completely normal that calling the function will consume memory if it is the first CUDA API containing function you call.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. At least I know that nothing is wrong with my code. And your answer to my second question is very helpful.